# Angular - Using a controller function in directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, controller

To start: I'm not having an error but try to optimize my code here.

I have an application where in many cases an address will be shown. This address should be editable in many cases. So I created a directive.

**My directive**

```
app.directive('addressview', function(medipracticeData) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'address-view.html',
        replace : true,
        scope : {
            address : '=',
            editAddress : '&?'
        },
        controller : function($scope){
            $scope.edit = function(){
                $scope.editAddress( { address : $scope.address } );
            }
        }
    };
});
```

**My directive template (address-view.html)**

```
<div ng-controller="AddressController as AddressCtrl">
    <addressview
        address="OfficeCtrl.office.address"
        edit-address="AddressCtrl.showAddressEdit(address)">
    </addressview>
</div>
```

As you can see, I am passing the `AddressCtrl.showAddressEdit()` function in every directive... This is the function in my Address Controller, which triggers a popup in which I can edit the address.

**My controller**

```
app.controller("AddressController", AddressController);

AddressController.$inject = ["$scope"];

function AddressController($scope) {

    var avm = this;
        avm.showAddressEdit = showAddressEdit;

    function showAddressEdit(address) {
        console.log(address);
    }
}
```

## My question

I'm trying to avoid passing this function `AddressCtrl.showAddressEdit()` to my directive all the time. Is it possible to use this function within my directive controller? So that everytime I use this directive, it would be usable as following:

```
<div ng-controller="AddressController as AddressCtrl">
    <addressview
        address="OfficeCtrl.office.address">
    </addressview>
</div>
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but 2 things:
You're using the `replace: true` attribute, which is deprecated. Don't use it anymore. Which angular version are you on?
Also, you could use a component instead of a directive, check it out: [components](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component)

Comment: Also, please [don't use ng-controller in your html](https://teropa.info/blog/2014/10/24/how-ive-improved-my-angular-apps-by-banning-ng-controller.html), and don't use scope, but rather use the `controllerAs` syntax, if you want to improve your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a Service, like this

```
angular.module("myModule").service("myService", function(){
    return {
        showAddressEdit: function(address) {
            console.log(address);
        }
    };
});
```

Then, you can inject it to your Controller in the directive/component like this:

```
// ...
controller : function($scope, myService){
        $scope.edit = function(){
            $scope.editAddress( { address : $scope.address } );
        }

        $scope.showAdressEdit = myService.showAdressEdit;
}
```